# overlaying two models for use in CNC relief carving

Tags: boolean-modifier

Is there a relatively easy way to overlay two models and delete faces/vectors of one model to appear behind the other? Specifically, an object to be behind tree branches.
(Complete and utter newbie)

Comment: Hello, what is CNC relief carving? Could you please show some pictures?

Comment: I don't think that it's easy as the second sculpting will overlay the first one, you can flatten it though